# Running .jar file from cmd returna "Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found" error

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I have a JavaFX project which runs perfectly well in IntelliJ, but when I tried to create a .jar and run it, I got this error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

So I ran

```
Java -jar --module-path C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Java\javafx-sdk-18.0.1\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.swing .\myJar.jar
```

which resulted in this:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:266)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:278)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: please do some research on how to deploy fx applications..

Comment: I tried it with Maven Shade and Maven Assembly, both got me the same error. How do I have to deploy my fx application for it to work?

Comment: You go to the [JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) and research the topic on packaging JavaFX applications.  You can also look at these [82 duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+QuantumRenderer%3A+no+suitable+pipeline+found).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by copying all JavaFX .dlls from `home/JavaFX-SDK/bin` to where my executable .jar is. None of the other suggestions were working.

I was working with Netbeans tho